require not defined error while deploy vite-react app
While deploying a vite-react app in Netlify I am getting white screen and require not defined error.
I tried removing "type":"module" from packag.json file.enter image description here
I was expecting to deploy my website in Netlify.

You can find the answer in this similar error here : Require is Undefined
Netlify does not have the Browserify node module installed globally, you will need to install it as a dev dependency at least to be able to run it locally.

Its not working. Its a vite react web app which I want to deploy in Netlify but , its giving require not defined error.
